# Lua make upvalue into constant

Tags: function, lua

The program, I'm writing lua script for, doesn't support saving of upvalues. Hence function `fun` would not be valid after restoring program state:

```
gen=function(par)
    local a=par
    return function() print(a) end
    end
fun=gen(2)
```

On the other hand simple functions without closures like `gen` are saved and loaded normally.
I'd like to create a bunch of functions similar to `fun` with different values of parameter `a` in the above. Programmatic equivalent of:

```
fun1=function()
    local a=1
    print(a)
end
fun2=function()
    local a=2
    print(a)
end
--and so on
```

Are there possibilities of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table that behaves just as your function (but, since it's a table, it should hopefully be restored correctly):

```
gen = function(par)
    return setmetatable({a = par}, {
            __call = function(self)
                print(self.a)
            end
        })
end

fun = gen(1)  -- Note: fun is a table, but can be called like a function.
fun()
```

If you need to add parameters to your table-function, you can simply do so by adding parameters to the `__call` metamethod:

```
gen = function(par)
    return setmetatable({a = par}, {
            __call = function(self, something)
                print(self.a, something)
            end
        })
end

fun = gen(1)
fun("foobar")   -- Outputs "1   foobar"
```

Check out the [Lua manual, section 'Metatables and Metamethods'](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4) for more info!